# How do I Revoke a particular FaceBook Access Token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

I can create as many Access Token as I want in facebook - even for example from [Graph API Tools](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)

that means: my app could use multiple access token for 1 particular user.

so I use this token in native mobile app to access user details (email, name, etc.) however, when user change their mobile phone, I have to revoke the access token that used to access the user details, and use another new access token for the new phone.
revoking the access token will be done in Server side (through PHP application).

however, i cant find any reference in Facebook developer on how to revoke a particular access token using PHP SDK (or even without any SDK).

i tried below:

```
$fb->delete( '/me/permissions, array (), $this->access_token );
// and 
$fb->delete( '/me/permissions?access_token='.$this->access_token, array (), $this->access_token );
```

but both code, is taking out user completly from my app (technically it will revoke all access token and re ask user again for permission - like the very first time user use my app)

so anyone knows how to revoke a particular FB access token using PHP?

cheers!

Comment: There is no way to do that. And I don't see why you would need to do that in the first place, what does this have to do with the user "changing" their phone?

Comment: The idea is: we dont want 1 single acct have 2 access token in 2 diffrent phone - means: if the user for any reason change/provision their acct to another phone, i would like to invalidate the old token. Well, yes i can always handle it 'internally' by revoking my own token, but technically the old access token is still valid and i wonder if there a way to kill that.

Comment: Are you hard-coding tokens in client-side code, or what is the issue? Are we talking about long-lived/extended tokens? If so, why are you using those in the first place - instead of a short-lived one, which would expire before this even becomes a problem?

Comment: Client request token from FB and send to server, then server keep it for future use. however on top of that my server has implement oauth2 internally, that means, the client not even able to communicate with server if my own oauth2 not valid. as I mentioned, i can revoke my own access token on the old phone. that solve the problem partially, but still not revoking the fb 'old' access token.

Comment: _"Client request token from FB and send to server, then server keep it for future use."_ - then what does the user switching their phone have to do with this ...?

Comment: when the user switching phone, the app will request authentication back to my server, when my server knows that this particular user was on the other phone, my intention is: to let the new phone sign-in and revoke the old phone access token... all of this activity done in server - because only server knows that the particular person/user was on the other phone or not

Comment: _"my intention is: to let the new phone sign-in and revoke the old phone access token..."_ - are you talking about your own OAuth's token here now? I still don't see how the Facebook token is an issue here.

Comment: I'm not talking about my own OAuth token, I'm looking if there a way to revoke a particular FB's Access Token.

Comment: The long and short answer to that is: No, there is not.